# How to sort an Object, which is really an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparable

I'm trying to figure out how to check if the component type of an array implements Comparable, and if so, sort the array. Here's what I have:

```
    if (prop1.getClass().isArray())
    {
        if (!(Array.getLength(prop1) == Array.getLength(prop2)))
            throw new AssertionError(objectName + "." + propertyName + "'s aren't the same length!");

        int len = Array.getLength(prop1);
        if (0 == len)
            return;

        List list1 = Arrays.asList(prop1);
        List list2 = Arrays.asList(prop2);
        // class names of objects in arrays are weird
        String componentClassName = StringUtils.remove(StringUtils.remove(list1.get(0).getClass().getName(), "[L"), ';');
        Class componentClazz = null;
        try
        {
            componentClazz = Class.forName(componentClassName);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(componentClazz))
        {
            Collections.sort(list1);
            Collections.sort(list2);
```

The first sort throws an exception when `prop1` is an array of String's:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to  java.lang.Comparable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prop1` is type `Object`, so `Arrays.asList(prop1)` returns a list of one element, the object aka the array. When you then try to sort the list, it's rightfully complaining that the element (actually an array of something) is not `Comparable`.

As for getting the array element type, you can't look at the first element, because it may be a subclass of the array element type. Just call `prop1.getClass().getComponentType()`.

To sort an array, call one of the 8 overloads of `Arrays.sort(a)`. Which one to call depends on the component type.

If you're not allowed to modify the original array, then clone it first.

**Update**

When I say "depends on the component type", I mean you have to check the type, and call the right version. Selecting a version of an overloaded method is done at compile-time, so it has to be done statically. *(well, another layer of reflection is another choice)*

```
Class<?> compType = prop1.getClass().getComponentType();
if (compType == int.class)
    Arrays.sort((int[])prop1);
else if (compType == float.class)
    Arrays.sort((float[])prop1);
// ... 5 more ...
else if (Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(compType))
    Arrays.sort((Comparable[])prop1);
else
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot sort array of " + compType.getName());
```

Comment: I can't call Arrays.sort() with an object. Would I need to use the component type to cast the object to an array of that component type before calling Arrays.sort()? I tried this, but using a reference to the Class to cast the object to an array of the class didn't work: `(clazz[]) object`

Comment: Yes, and in 8 different ways, how else will the compiler know which one you want to call? Remember, the generics version cannot be used for arrays of primitives, because a generic cannot be a primitive. So, 7 different primitive types (if you need to support all of them), and a version for `Comparable`.

Comment: `Arrays.sort((clazz[]) object)` is not allowed (`Class clazz = prop1.getClass().getComponentType()`)

Comment: I would expect you'd need to write `Arrays.sort((Comparable[]) array)`.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks @LouisWasserman! @Andreas your update has this too, thanks!